# How to get data from a thread to the UI in C# (How to use backgroundWorker)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker

In my application, I am using a Data Grid View. The data to be filled in the data grid view are in another thread.

How can I get data from another thread to the Data Grid View? How can I use background worker for this? (Please find the sample code below)

Please help. I am new to c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ex1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("1", "Sno"); 
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("2", "Time");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("3", "Name");
    }
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Get data from MyThread and add new row to dataGridView1.

    //Like,
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sno,time,name); // strings from MyThread

}

#region EVENT THTEAD (RX)
    public void MyThread()
    {
        // Each time button2 press, took data from here and add that to dataGridView1 as a new row.

        String sno= "some value";
        String time="some value";
        String name="some value";

     }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the sno, time and name variables from outside your MyThread() scope, you should move the declarations to outer scope. Like this:

```
String sno;
String time;        
String name;

public void MyThread()
    {
        // Each time button2 press, took data from here and add that to dataGridView1 as a new row.

        sno= "some value";
        time="some value";
        name="some value";

     }
```

To update your UI from another thread, you can create this class with an extension method:

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
            }
            else
            {
                action(@this);
            }
        }
}
```

And then from your other "data"-thread, you can use it like this:

```
 this.InvokeEx(f => f.myTextBox.Text = "Some tekst from another thread");
```

But you do have to bring in your own action with some datagrid logic instead of this textbox example... Something like this:

```
this.InvokeEx(f => f.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sno,time,name));
```

In case you are not familiar with this, Here's some info about extention methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

And here's some info about Actions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx